# Jquery trigger event o clicking hyper link

Tags: jquery

Im new in jquery. I have some links in my page like the below:

```
<a href="http://google.com/" rel="gb_page_fs[]">Details</a>
```

I want to write a jquery function that will trigger only if the hyper link contains rel="gb_page_fs[]. And it will open google.com (or whatever url is given within href) in a popup window. Basically I want trigger a function like below once the link is clicked. But I dont want to add any additional element within the  tag.

```
function myFunction() {
    window.open("http://google.com", "_blank", "toolbar=yes,     scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, top=500, left=500, width=400, height=400");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using jQuery, you can bind events in this way:

```
$("a[rel='gb_page_fs[]']").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    window.open($(this).attr('href'), "_blank", "toolbar=yes, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, top=500, left=500, width=400, height=400")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.attr("rel")` to access the value of the attribute and test to see if it matches your expected value.